# Changing caption of form changes color of System bar Caption Background?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

on some button click i am setting the Caption of form to a filename like this:

```
var
FileName: String;
....

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObjecT);
begin
  Caption:= FileName;
end;
```

I am using FMXStyle Coral Dark.

This is the Image: [image: The System Bar]

Comment: I assume you are running on Windows, right? Does it stay like that for the rest of the run time? Also if you minimize - restore the window?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes i am running it on windows. and This is not permanent. it get normal when i click on the SystemBar. But why it's getting this blue background in the caption of the main form ?

Comment: I don't seem to have "Coral Dark" with my XE7. Do you see the same effect with some other styles, like `Dark.Style`, `Blend.Style`, `Carbon.Style` or ..?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Literally with every style. With Jet one too.

Comment: the blue background vanishes when i  hover the mouse on minimize button.

Comment: I just realized, that the window frame is not styled in XE7 with any of the available styles. Thus, hard to investigate. Hopefully somebody else can chime in.